# npm install child_process not working

Tags: node.js

I wanted to use child_process module to run a script from node.js but when I run command

> npm install child_process I get the following error :

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ChildProcess
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/ChildProcess
npm ERR! 404 'ChildProcess' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
```

Just wondering is the child_process module removed or am I misspelling the module name.

Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You don't have to install it as a module, it comes bundled with node.js. http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: I get this error though. Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process'

Answer (score 4):

I searched in https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/child_process , there is no content about child_process.  just require('child_process') and use it .