# Entering Windows 10 sleep mode programmatically with Node.js

Tags: node.js, windows-10, sleep-mode

I want to be able to programmatically make my Windows 10 computer enter sleep mode using Node.js.

What can I write to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const {exec} = require('child_process');
exec("rundll32.exe powrprof.dll, SetSuspendState Sleep");
```

The `require` statement lets you use a Node.js module that can execute native Windows commands. This module comes [bundled with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872459/npm-install-child-process-not-working) so you don't need to install it.